# Extract alpha channel from webm video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I'm trying to extract a mask from a webm video with alpha transparency:

```
ffmpeg -i test.webm -vf "alphaextract" -y output.mp4
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
[Parsed_alphaextract_2 @ 0x7f924b700d00] Requested planes not available.
[Parsed_alphaextract_2 @ 0x7f924b700d00] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_alphaextract_2
```

Am I doing something wrong? The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphaextract) for *alphaextract* is surprisingly sparse.

Here's the *ffprobe* readout:

```
ffprobe version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libvpx --enable-libopus --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 407 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 480x244, SAR 1:1 DAR 120:61, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
```

Comment: Please paste the readout of ffprobe for the file.

Comment: Done. Also it's worth mentioning that I created this webm from an mp4 and a mask, I'm now trying to work out how to do the reverse.

Comment: I've made a few VP8 with alpha myself, and the alpha doesn't seem to be stored traditionally i.e. as an adjunct plane. Let me check.

Comment: [Seems](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-January/019283.html) not possible with ffmpeg.

Comment: Damn, that is a shame.  Thanks @Mulvya, please feel free to post an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, none of ffmpeg's VP8 decoders seem able to decode alpha in VP8 video streams. This [post](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-January/019283.html) from the ffmpeg-user mailing list suggests it's due to the unusual method by which alpha is [stored](http://wiki.webmproject.org/alpha-channel) within the stream.

Might be worth looking at [webm-tools](http://www.webmproject.org/code/).

Comment: This information is outdated. Decoding with alpha is possible via `libvpx-vp9` (see other answer).

Answer (score 4):

Since 2016-07-20, it's possible to decode properly a webm with alpha channel (VP8a or VP9a) but you need `-vcodec libvpx` option. You must download an **FFmpeg** compiled after that date (or compile yourself with up-to-date commits) and use the following command:

`ffmpeg -vcodec libvpx -i test.webm -vf alphaextract -y output.mp4`

Note that `-vcodec libvpx` is **before** the input, not after it.